# Creating a Google Develper's Account

Tags: google-api

I'm having no luck in trying to create a Google Developer's Account.  I appreciate instructions have been posted in Stackoverflow in the past but the process or web pages have since changed.  I've been to the Developer's Console and created a Project but I can't access the Project itself. My objective is to create the Developer's Account to get the API key to code the service into a client-server application that includes geocoding - reverse, and address lookup to return latitude and longitudes.  Thereafter, I wish to be able to advise my clients how they can create client accounts to access the service.  Any step-by-step advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. This is an interesting question, but sadly not really a good fit for Stack Overflow. S/O works best for specific, technical questions that have a right answer - usually bug-fixing your code. It's less well adapted to guiding you through a setup process. Perhaps you could contact Google Developer Support to ask them to help you out?

Comment: I agree with @TarynEast this is not a good question for stack but.  Try this link:  http://www.daimto.com/google-development-beginners/

Comment: I apologise for stepping outside the bounds but, as stated, prior posts received some good and appreciated feedback.  The recommended 'daimto' site looks very useful but, unfortunately, it doesn't advise on how to open a Developer's Account.  I've contacted Google Support on how to achieve this.  Thanks for your advice and interest.